# Saving Scraped Data to CSV Files

Tags: python, scrapy

I used to save the scraped data via `scrapy crawl name -o name.csv`as a CSV file.

Therefore I used to yield all the data:

```
yield {
   name: name,
   phone: phone
}
```

now I would like to write the data into CSV files with 100 entries each.

What is the simplest way to save it to CSV a 100 entries each?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Post-processing :)